# How do I keep my UTF-8 characters from becoming junk?

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm creating a simple JavaScript multiple choice game. Here is a sample question:

```
p ∧ q ≡ q ∧ p by which rule?
```

When I run it on localhost, it works fine, it prints out those special characters. However, when I upload it to my school's server, it prints out garbage:

```
p âˆ¨ q â‰¡ q âˆ¨ p by which rule?
```

I have this at the top of my HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I can't use PHP in my assignment, or I'd use `header('Content-Type: text/xml, charset=utf-8');`

If you want, I can give a link... but I'd rather not because then everyone can see my really bad educational game...

How can I keep my UTF-8 characters?

**Edit:** I found out that if I Filezilla my files up to the server and download them from the server, the characters become little squares. I don't know if that's useful information.

Comment: Spontaneous guess: your school's server outputs a `Content-Type` header by default, which you can't override with your meta tag. Try to confirm that with Firebug/Web Inspector/any other tool that shows you HTTP headers.

Comment: Yes! When I click Page Info I see Encoding: ISO-8859-1. Any way to get around that?

Comment: Depends on the server. Can you override the output header using an .htaccess file?

Comment: I don't know... I don't think I have access to that file. I found something that I think is useful here: http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets where they override it with that php header() command, but I'm not supposed to use php til next project

Comment: In that case, talk to your school. :)

Comment: If you're simply not *supposed to* use PHP, I'd probably do it anyway, since it is necessary to ensure correct display and really entirely seperate from the point of the task. If you can't/don't want to, the (proper) alternatives would be to override it using some other mechanism (such as .htaccess, but it depends on what server is used and what it allows), use images, or use questions and answers that don't require Unicode. In a pinch, you should also be able to use HTML entities instead of raw characters, but IMO, that's kind of like using a chainsaw to pick flowers: works, but very messy.

Comment: Welp, I tried putting a bit of PHP at the beginning, but then I messed up the file permissions deal or something. I'm saying screw it and changing the characters from ∧ to A and the like. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot easily fix the HTTP headers, escape from the problem by using “character escapes.” If e.g. “∧” occurs in HTML content, use `&#x2227;` for it. If it occurs in a JavaScript string literal, use `\u2227` for it.

To check out the codes for other characters, consult e.g.
http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/mathematical_operators.html

Comment: Definitely should have gone this route for this particular problem. On my next assignment I'll just use PHP, but this assignment I should have done this (due three hours ago). Really good stuff to know though and so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Edit: I found out that if I Filezilla my files up to the server and download them from the server, the characters become little squares. I don't know if that's useful information.

Yes, filezilla is corrupting your files in transit. Make sure filezilla transfers your files as binary in order to make sure the text doesn't get corrupted in transit. If its transferring in ascii mode, it'll try to fix newlines and unrecognized characters.

Comment: I'm currently trying to do this. I tried it once and it didn't work, trying it again. This sounds promising.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend using scp or sftp not plain old ftp; of course I'm assuming that FileZilla is used for only ftp. Sftp/scp is more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Copying and pasting the questions into notepad or any other app that allows you to save as UTF-8 might work if that is a viable option.

I think you could also use a regex to identify the hex values and replace them with the corresponding value that would work in UTF8.

Also if you're using a specialized type of font this could cause the problem - are the questions stylized with a particular font? a set of fallbacks? you may need to do an @font-face import but I suspect there's another option...with the symbols you're trying to use it seems like LaTeX might be an option..I believe there are a few options out there for javascript, fonts, etc..

this article may also be useful: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/printerFriendly/articles/Unicode.html